# pygame not loading music file

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I want to get a music on playlist and load it, but it's returning :

```py
File "c:/Users/User/Documents/Python-testes/teste-2.py", line 25, in play
    mixer.music.load(filenames)
pygame.error: Couldn't open 'C:/Python/Playlist/BØRNS - Electric Love.mp3'
```

I tried to use the `.wav` archive too but keeps returning this error, I'm using the `vsc` and the Python 3.8.8 version and pygame 2.0.1, this is my code:

```
from tkinter import Listbox, Tk
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.constants import ACTIVE, END
from pygame import mixer
import pygame



def play_song():
    filenames = list(filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir = "C:/Python/Playlist/", title = "Please select a file", filetypes=(("Mp3 Files", "*.mp3"),)))
    for song in filenames:
        song = song.split("/")
        song = song[-1]
        Playlist_box.insert(END,song)


def play():
    filenames = Playlist_box.get(Playlist_box.curselection())
    filenames = (f'C:/Python/Playlist/{filenames}')
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(filenames)
    mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    


root = Tk()
root.title('music')
label = Label(root, 
    text="choose the song").pack()

Playlist_box = Listbox(root, bg="black", fg="green", width=60)
Playlist_box.pack()

Button(root, text="choose your songs", command=play_song).pack()
Button(root, text="Play music", padx=12, bg="black", fg="white", command= play).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I also tried to put the file path but the error is the same.

Comment: Most probably that you have selected songs not within `'D:/Python/Playlist/'` directory.

Comment: they are in this directory

Comment: Can you load the file in the interactive Python console? Spaces in the path might be an issue.

Comment: Maybe the `Ø` character is not recognized by PyGame? Either way, PyGame is more comfortable with `.wav` and `.ogg` files, there can be some problems with `.mp3` files. Try converting it to another format, and see if the error persists. This case the audio file might be corrupted.

Comment: I agree with @D_00 here. This is probably due to the format or the file name (python doesn't like accents in general). Try with another song perhaps

Comment: I change the music, for one whitout spaces in the name and without character, tried to change to .wav too, but continues not working and with the same error. I have a mp3 player that don't use playlist and he play the song normaly, i dont know what i do, it's the same error but i don't find where it can be.

Answer (score 0):

the error was in 'filenames' directory call,
i put :

```
filenames = (f'C:/Python/Playlist/{filenames}')
```

but it supose to be

```
filenames = (f'C:/Users/User/Documents/Python/Playlist/{filenames}')
```

he's working now, thank you people but it was just the call directory!!